# How many universal cones from $\Delta_{A\times A}$ to D?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, natural-transformations

I have drawn the picture like the following.

[image]

Let $C$ is a category (suppose $Set$), $I$ is a category with only two objects (1 and 2), $\Delta_{A\times A}$ and $D$ are constant functors from $I$ to C.

A cone on $D$ with a vertex $u$ is a natural transformation from $\Delta_{u}$ to $D$. A limit of D is a universal cone, that is for any cone on $D$ there exists a unique factorization.

Obviously the product $A \times A$ equipped with two projections $fst$ and $snd$ is a limit of $D$.

My question is that how many universal cones (or limits) on $D$?

On the surface there seems to be only one universal cone, but I thinks there are two.

The reason is that a cone is essentially a natural transformation that satisfies some commuting conditions.

In Mac Lane p.16, he said that

> a natural transformation is a function... which assigns to each object c of C an arrow $τ_{c} = τc : S_c \to T_{c}$  of B in such a way ...

[image]

There are two such natural transformations, i.e. $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

$\alpha: \Delta_{A\times A} \to D$ with 2 components

$\alpha_{1} = fst: A \times A \to A$

$\alpha_{2} = snd: A \times A \to A$

$\beta: \Delta_{A\times A} \to D$ with 2 components

$\beta_{1} = snd: A \times A \to A$

$\beta_{2} = fst: A \times A \to A$

Here, the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are obviously different functions.

Am I correct?

Thanks.

---

For clarity, I've slightly edited the question, but the overall point remains unchanged.

Comment: it depends heavily on your cat! essentially, by your setup, what you should get is that your functor cat $\mathrm{Fun}\left(I,C\right)$ coincides with the product cat $C\times C$ and so your natural transformations are literally the product of ALL morphisms $C\left(\Delta , D\right)^{\oplus 2}$

Comment: @Felix Sorry, I'm a novice of category theory. I don't quite understand what you said. What does the symbol $C(Δ,D)^{⊕2}$ mean?

Comment: The naturality condition is vacuous because there are no non-identity morphisms in  $I$ at all. So all (un)natural transformations will be natural.

Comment: @Trebor My confusion mainly focus on the definition of natural transformation, especially the point of view of "function" (in Mac Lane). Do you think α and β be considered as two natural transformations or just one?

Comment: @chansey it is the product of the hom space between the two with itself. Essentially objects are the same as functors from the category with 1 object into a category, and you just pick out 2 objects, so your functors just pick 2 objjects, and so the natural transformations are just maps between these 2 objects.

Comment: @Trebor Maybe I should add an additional condition, says "how many universal cones from ΔA×A to D"? But the points are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An immediate consequence of the universal property is that between any two universal cones $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ and $(\beta_1,\beta_2)$ there are unique morphisms $b$ and $a$ for which $b\circ\alpha_i=\beta_i$ and $a\circ\beta_i=\alpha_i$. But then $a\circ b\circ\alpha_i=a\circ\beta_i=\alpha_i$ and $b\circ a\circ\beta_i=b\circ\alpha_i=a_i$. Another application of the universal property then yields that $a\circ b=\mathrm{id}$ and $b\circ a=\mathrm{id}$, i.e. that $a$ and $b$ are inverse isomorphisms.

Thus the answer to the question is that if there is at least one universal cone, say $\beta_1,\beta_2\colon B\rightrightarrows A$, then you have as many universal cones as isomorphisms with domain $B$.

Of particular interest to you seem to be other universal cocones with the same vertex $B$, which would correspond to automorphisms of $B$, i.e. isomorphisms of $B$ with itself. These in general depend on the category, but certain of the isomorphisms do not, i.e. those constructed from the projection morphisms alone.

Explcitly, the univeral property implies that endomorphism $B\to B$ correspond to cones $B\rightrightarrows A$, and there are exactly four that can be constructed from the two projections $\beta_1,\beta_2\rightrightarrows A$: $(\beta_1,\beta_2)$, $(\beta_1,\beta_1)$, $(\beta_2,\beta_2)$, and $(\beta_2,\beta_1)$. These correspond to the identity, left, right, and reverse endomorphisms of $B$. The identity and reverse endomorphisms are the only isomorphisms. Thus every universal cone has exactly one other universal cone structure that exists independently of the ambient category.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still have some confusion need some clarification to confirm I have understand what you said. (1) Is you composition symbol ∘ read from left to right? E.g. In you answer "$b∘α_{i}=β_{i}$", it actually means $b;α_{i}=β_{i}$ or $α_{i}∘b=β_{i}$, right? I usually read from right to left.

Comment: (2) You mentioned that "These in general depend on the category". In the question I said "Let C is a category (suppose Set)", so in $Set$, can I conclude that there are exactly two universal cones? i.e. $(α1,α2)$ and $(β1,β2)$.

Comment: (3) You mentioned that "you have as many universal cones as isomorphisms with domain B." This seems to need proof, but I believe you are right. What do you think about the Mac Lane's definition of natural transformation? Do you think my understanding is correct? i.e. Using his definition to derive the number of universal cones.

Comment: In terms of natural transformations. Fix $D\colon\mathcal I\to\mathcal C$. Constant functors $I\to\mathcal C$ are in bijection with objects of $\mathcal C$, so label them as such. Morphisms $B'\to B$ in $\mathcal C$ correspond under the bijection to natural transformations between constant functors. Cones correspond to natural transformations $B\Rightarrow D$. If $B\Rightarrow D$ is a universal cone, then so is $B'\cong B\Rightarrow D$, where $B'\cong B$ is a natural isomorphism of constant functors. I've shown the converse, hence the correspondence.

Comment: "Another application of the universal property then yields that a∘b=id and b∘a=id, i.e. that a and b are inverse isomorphisms." Sorry, I still can't get this result. I have little experience with category theory proofs. Could you give me some hint? Thanks.

Comment: $\beta_i\colon B\rightrightarrows A$ is a universal cone if for any other cone $\beta'_i\colon B'\rightrightarrows A$, there is a unique morphism $b\colon B'\to B$ for which $b\circ\beta'_i=\beta_i$. In particular, $a\circ b$ and $b\circ a$ in my example as well as the identity morphisms satisfy the property, so must coincide by uniqueness.

Comment: I think I got your point. This is another way says that "Limits and colimits, when they exist, are unique up to unique isomorphism" A proof, see (if someone is interested): https://www.quora.com/How-does-one-show-that-any-two-limits-of-a-diagram-are-isomorphic-in-Category-Theory  Thanks.